# why MySQL select query doesn't pass all queried rows in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter

I've been working on a codeigniter project.In that i have to show outlets names(nearly 4880 tuples) using a drop down(using html select tag).

So I write javascript function as below.

```js
function get_out_info() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: URL + 'implementation/get_outlt_info',
                    data: {
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        var ajagx = JSON.parse(data);
                        var rows = ['<option value="0" >Select outlets { ' + ajagx.length + ' results }</option>'];
                        for (var x = 0; x < ajagx.length; x++) {
                            rows.push('<option value="' + ajagx[x].idoutlet + '">' + ajagx[x].o_name + '</option>');
                        }
                        $('#out_id').empty().append(rows);

                    }
                });
            }
```

But, dropdown only populated when i use limit clause in my model as below.

```
function get_outlet_info() {
        $query_outlt = "SELECT o_name, idoutlet FROM tbl_outlet WHERE o_active = 1 limit 2000";
        return $this->db->query($query_outlt);
    }
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: The first thing to check is whether the 4880 tuples are all in the JSON response. If they are, you might be running into some arbitrary browser limit - though honestly I'd be surprised if it was that low. But that at least narrows the debugging to one end or the other.

Comment: I'm using XAMPP and i execute the above query using phpmyadmin in the same browser(google chrome) and it showed all the tuples.

Comment: start by doing a `console.log(ajagx)` just after you set that var this will allow you to see whether the values are getting passed back from the URL correctly. The they are all showing correctly there you will most likely have an issue with the bit of code that is adding the rows to the select box.

Comment: I've alert the data in success but it only work for 4000 rows.